# What happens when Gmail quota is exceeded?

Tags: gmail

I have tried finding the answer, but it didn't exist.

Comment: The answer to this is good but the question itself is lacking. It might be good if you could explain something along the lines of you were looking at your current usage and quota (explaining where that is) and were getting close, so you wanted to know if you'll continue to receive messages afterwards.

Answer (score 12):

Nothing appears to happen until you reach close to 105% utilisation (e.g., [image: <code>You're currently using 16007 MB (104%) of your 15360 MB</code>]), at which point, messages get temporarily rejected as follows, after the [`RCPT TO` command](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.sbin/smtpd/smtp_session.c#CMD_RCPT_TO) is issued:

```
452-4.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct
452-4.2.2 the recipient to
452 4.2.2  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaTemp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - gsmtp
```

Here's the link as a hyperlink: https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaTemp

Comment: If someone sends a message to me and I'm over quota, do they have to re-send the message when I free up space, or does it wait in a queue and then appear once I have enough space?

Comment: `452-4.2.2` is a temporary error code; so, the message will wait in the queue of the sending server; note that due to being a temporary code, the sender usually wouldn't even be notified that the message is delayed (until such time that a timeout is reached, and the sending server would thus return the message back to the sender)

Comment: an interesting observation is that freeing up the space from 16007MB to 15998MB (both are reported as 104%), didn't make the space for accepting any new messages.

Comment: also, for completeness sake, I'd like to point out that this was a very gradual increase in disc space use, e.g., it went from 100% to 104% in about a month or two, during which time there was no apparent decrease in gmail functionality